# font-weight property is not working in inline style

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

I am inserting html code through database, we don't have separate styling sheet. So we are using inline styling.

I used below code

```
<li style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt;Color: #711984; font-weight: bold">
 Cross-border Transfer
</li>
```

But font-weight property is not applicable, I don't see bold fonts.

I tried below code, it works but I don't think its recommended for best practices:

```
<b>
<li style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13pt;Color: #711984;">
 Cross-border Transfer
</li>
</b>
```

Pl

Comment: Your code works for me. https://codepen.io/whoacowboy/pen/KKRgYaa You'd want to put the `<b>` tag inside the `<li>` tag if you wanted to do it that way.

Comment: Instead of using `font-weight: bold;`, try using `font-weight: 900;` or another numerical value. Values are `100`, `200`, up through `900`.

Comment: I agree with whoacowboy (but you should rather use the recommended more semantic  `<strong>`  tags). The fact you don't see bold applied in your first code indicates, there might be actually some overriding css rule for list elements somewhere in you template or event invoked by a javaScript.